# Enterprise Architect: Export UML Diagrams in high quality

Tags: uml, image, class-diagram, enterprise-architect

With Enterprise Architect (Version 9.2), I created some Class and Sequence UML Diagrams. Now I need those Diagrams in a Word document.

My first approach was to just cut them out with the Windows 7 Snipping Tool and paste them into the document. But for printing purposes the quality was way too poor.

The second approach was to "Save them as Images" as offered in Enterprise Architect. But with this, the quality was even worse.

The third way was to export them into a pdf file. With this the quality was quite decent and I could import those pdfs into Inkscape and then convert them into *.png files to import them to word. The problem is, that Enterprise Architect kinda fails with the fonts. Meaning the picture itself has high-quality, but it tries to convert the font of the classes and then I have some spaces between letters where there should be none.

So long story short - is there a way to export my UML Diagrams from Enterprise Architect to a common picture format like `.png` or `.tiff`, while retaining decent quality?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

As I'm sure you're already aware, you can save a diagram as an image in several formats, including PNG but not TIFF.

The quality of the images can be controlled in the options (Tools - Options), "Diagram" tab.
The "Image Memory Limit" controls the amount of memory the image conversion process is allowed; increasing this should improve the quality of large diagrams.
"Scale Saved Bitmaps to" allows you to set a higher resolution for the images.

I haven't checked whether these also affect the copy-to-clipboard function (in the Diagram menu or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), which is the way I usually copy diagrams into documents.

Comment: Ah great, this actually helps a lot - I scaled the Bitmap export to 400% and defined 512MB of memory for hte image conversion. Now I can save the diagrams in a png file with quite a decent quality. Problem is that my word now fails at the pdf export ( loses quality ) but okay thats not part of this particular problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Ctrl + T is the short-cut for saving a diagram as an image file

Comment: EA 13: Start -> Preferences -> Diagram

Answer (score 28):

To have diagrams in word there is very easy way.

Simply, open diagram in ea then select all with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then copy <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, go in word and just do paste <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Easy and perfect quality.

Comment: sometimes large class diagrams are cutoff using this approach.

Comment: I already had finished my question here on SO before finding this. Well, I was searching for use case export, not uml. This works nicely, many thanks! BTW, you can also select parts of the diagram, this works just as well!

Comment: As of EA 12.1, this puts a "fake" metafile on the clipboard.  It's actually a bad-quality JPG wrapped in a metafile.  This is also what happens if you save as EMF or WMF.  Also, the image has cleartype baked into it, so it is no good for printing.

Answer (score 12):

For some reason, when you use Ctrl-B to export a Sparx EA model to MS Word, you get a bitmap copied to the clipboard, but when you paste into Powerpoint, you get an Enhanced Metafile. This is vector graphics which can be zoomed into etc. with no loss of detail.

Prep

1. Before you start, go into EA and Tools->Options (or hit Ctrl-F9).
2. Ensure that the General properties page is selected.
3. Check 'Clipboard' is set to 'Metafile' (if it is set to Bitmap, you will
   only ever get a bitmap produced, even in Powerpoint).

Steps

1. Open your EA model to be exported.
2. Open Powerpoint and clear the default bounding boxes leaving a blank slide.
3. Open Word and locate the point in your document where you want to paste the model.
4. Back to EA, open your model window and hit Ctrl-B (Diagram->Paste Image to Clipboard)
5. Go into Powerpoint and hit Ctrl-V to paste.
6. Resize the model to fit the slide.
7. Hit Ctrl A then Ctrl C to ensure everything is copied to the clipboard.
8. Go into Word and hit Ctrl-V to paste - you should now have an EA model in EMF metafile format, not a bitmap. Document reviewers can now zoom in and see the full detail in the model.

Comment: As of EA 21.1, this puts a "fake" metafile on the clipboard.  It's actually a bad-quality JPG wrapped in a metafile.  This is also what happens if you save as EMF or WMF.

Comment: I meant 12.1, sorry.

Comment: I'm using EA 14. I just tested to paste it directly into word and I can zoom it without loosing quality, so I guess now the metafile gets pasted into word as well instead of the bmp.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

PACKAGE->Documetation->Publish as HTML

Create new folder for output and set the path in"Output" field.

-> Press Generate

Goto ..[your folder]\EARoot, the files named EA*.[png|gif] are your diagram

images in original resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Myself, I used ctrl+P and used my pdf converter for printing. 
- Before this, I setup the page size in the Diagram properties -> Diagram -> Page Setup -> Advanced. 
- I set "Scale to one page" then i click "Page Setup", choose the appropriate page size and orientation. 
- My PDF converter is PDFCreator: http://download.cnet.com/PDFCreator/3000-2064_4-10558866.html

Comment: There is no "Advanced" in my "Page Setup" dialog. Otherwise this sounds like a reasonably nice workflow.

Comment: This is a print option that depends on the operating system/printing software. In Any case you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

While I see that you seem to have this resolved (happy to hear), I'll post this in case others don't have any luck with the above.

I've always just selected (ctrl+A for the whole diagram) and pasted in to Word/PPT/Outlook and the diagrams were converted automatically to nice PNG scalable images (without ever changing the memory/quality settings).

But on a recent project it seems that when I tried to do the same the quality was very poor/fuzzy and the text was sort of squashed.

Are you by chance using Remote Desktop to connect to a machine that is Running Sparx EA? There is another thread floating around somewhere (sorry don't have the link) where others were having this similar trouble when connected via RDP in Full screen display mode. I was able to export good quality from a non-RDP session, or I think if I connected via RDP but not in Full-Screen mode it owuld export in the quality I'm used to.

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue

Answer (score 1):

Change your diagram themes, go to tools->diagram->Themes and change diagram themes to "blueprint" and go to file->Print to PDF

Answer (score 0):

With Version 13 (probably older versions as well) you can press `Ctrl-T` to open the dialog "Save as Image". There you can choose between .png, .bmp, .jpeg, .tga, .gif, .wmf and .emf.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the diagram <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>  and paste it into Microsoft Paint and then save it as `jpg/png` file.